# how to assign value in to array in c#

Tags: c#, sql, model-view-controller

First of all get the rolename based on the login user. After that get the functioncode from db based on the role. I need to assign the `sql` result into `Array`, but it keep show error `can't convert from string to string[]`

```
   public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
        DEV_Context OE = new DEV_Context();
        string role = OE.UserRefs.Where(x => x.UserName == username).FirstOrDefault().RoleName;

        string[] permission = OE.RolePermissionRefs.Where(x => x.RoleName == role).FirstOrDefault().FunctionCode; 
        string[] result={permission};

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Why dont you just return permission; ? Further more I advice you to use Collection-Types instead of arrays. So for example List<string>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need array of string, so instead of using FirstOrDefault, use [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx) and than [ToArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb298736(v=vs.100).aspx) method.

Your method should look like

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
{
    DEV_Context OE = new DEV_Context();
    string role = OE.UserRefs.Where(x => x.UserName == username).FirstOrDefault().RoleName;

    string[] result= OE.RolePermissionRefs.Where(x => x.RoleName == role).Select(x=>x.FunctionCode).ToArray(); 

    return result;
}
```